# Saved image in Documents and I need to reference as URL

Tags: url, document

I have an image that I have saved to Documents object in Salesforce. I need to be able to reference this as a URL I keep seeing reference to servlet url, but nothing on how to build one: /servlet/servlet.ImageServer?

How do I use the image id to construct a URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Salesforce Classic under the documents tab if you select the image you have uploaded and hit the view file button as shown below.
[image: View File Button]

you can then get the /servlet/ section from the URL of the image opened in a new tab.

[image: Image URL]